How to assert the value of a collection in NUnit with a collection expression whose type is inferred from the test value
I can assert the value of an array utilising collection expressions in NUnit like this:
var arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Assert.That(arr, Is.EquivalentTo((int[])[1, 2, 7, 3]));

I would like to write
var arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Assert.That(arr, Is.EquivalentTo([1, 2, 7, 3]));

EquivalentTo() expects an untyped IEnumerable, it should expected an array or enumerable of the same type as arr.
Is there a direct way in NUnit to achieve this?
The problem I see is that the type of the test value does affect the constraint (Is.Equivalen), so NUnit's constraint system is sort of untyped.
Without idiomatic constraints, I can use a utility method:
void AssertCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll, IEnumerable<T> expected)
{
    Assert.That(coll, Is.EquivalentTo(expected));
}

AssertCollection(arr, [1, 2, 7, 3]);


NUnits constraint system is not typed (much). As a quick way to nicely write test values as collection expression I use this extension method
public static void HasValues<T> (this IEnumerable<T> coll, params T[] expected)
{
    Assert.That(coll, Is.EquivalentTo(expected));
}

to write tests so:
arr.HasValues([1, 2, 7, 3]); // array
arr.HasValues(1, 2, 7, 3); // params array

